# how to check if the current item is available in the cart list in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs ecommerce app for that I need to check in productDetail Page is the product is already available in cart page. Both of the components have different api endpoint. I am not sure how to do that. I am using react-redux for state management.

CartActions.js

```
export const getItemsAddedToCart = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: cartActionTypes.GET_CART_LOAD
  });
  new _rest()
    .get(URLConstants.urls.GET_ALL_ITEMS_IN_CART)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: cartActionTypes.GET_CART_SUCCESS,
        payload: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: cartActionTypes.GET_CART_ERROR,
        error: err
      });
    });
};



export const IsItemInCart = (pId) => ({
  type: cartActionTypes.CHECK_ITEM_IN_CART,
  pId
});
```

These are my actions inside productDetails page i am passing product id inside IsItemIncart. Then In reducer I am trying to look into cart ans update state.

CartReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  loaded: false,
  error: null,
  itemsInCart: null,
  pagination: null,
  totalamount: 0,
  checkedItems: [],
  paymentStatus: "NIL_TRANSACTION",
  order: {
    addressId: "NIL",
    paymentType: "NIL"
  },
  isItemInCart: false,
  bulkOrderData: []
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {



    case cartActionTypes.GET_CART_LOAD:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false
      };

    case cartActionTypes.GET_CART_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loaded: true,
        loading: false,
        totalItemInCart: action.payload._embedded.cartResourceList.length,
        itemsInCart: action.payload._embedded.cartResourceList,
        totalamount: action.payload._embedded.cartResourceList.reduce(
          (acc, item) => {
            return item.totalAmount + acc;
          },
          0
        ),
        pagination: action.payload.page
      };
    case cartActionTypes.CHECK_ITEM_IN_CART:
      const findItem = state.itemsInCart.findIndex(
          productId => productId === action.pid
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        isItemInCart: true,

        /*
        *  Check For Item In Cart Here
        * */
      };
```

Here is My reducer I want to check them here which i am not sure how to do that.

Comment: The ID of each product must be unique so maybe you can compare using that.

Comment: i have never done this before thats y i m confuse how should i do this in reducer.

Comment: Okay, no issues....rather than doing it in the reducer you should compare the IDs in the action(as you have access to state their as well) and if a particular ID is not there in the card then you can send it to the reducer for adding the Product object.

Comment: Both are coming from different api endpoint I have written different actions for both of them. How is this going to possible in actions.

Comment: Okay, but you must be saving them somewhere in the state? then you ca n dispatch the state from the action

Comment: In actions you will be having access to both the reducers, so before adding item to cart, you can get cart data from its reducer , check whether the product with same id exists in cart data and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Actions in redux are meant to transform the state as you've done with `getItemsAddedToCart`. `IsItemInCart` is not how you should use actions as checking whether a particular item is in the cart is a derived property that can be calculated outside the store (in the component or otherwise) like below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getItemsAddedToCart } from './CartActions';

// these will get mapped to the components props
// using the connect function from react-redux
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchCartItems: () => dispatch(getItemsAddedToCart())
})

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    cartList: state.cart.itemsInCart,
});

class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // if has not been fetched yet
    if (!this.props.cartList) {
      this.props.fetchCartItems();
    }
  }

  checkItemInCart(pID) {
    return this.props.cartList.find(
       (product) => product.id === pID);
  }


   ....
   ....
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExampleComponent);
```

Read [usage with react](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react).

Comment: I have edited my answer and added some code. Can please look into it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if you need any help :)

Comment: I did This and it works but the only issue is `const checkItemInCart =() => {

        if(cartList !== null) {
            return cartList.find((product) => product.productId === productDetail.productId ||false );
        }

    }`  . I want to update text using this function like this `{!checkItemInCart()  ? 'Add To Cart' : 'Added To Cart'}` Here i have to refresh to see change.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to return the find value. I've updated the code. You don't need to do || false part as find will return undefined which evaluates to false.

Also in the function you are not using `this.props.cartList`.

Answer (score 0):

In CartAction.js

```
export const IsItemInCart = (productId) => {
 return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // you can use your cart reducer name instead of cartData
    const cartData = getState().cartData;
    // match your productId with your products in cart
    const product = cartData.find((singleProductInCart) => {return singleProductInCart.productId === productId});
    // then proceed further depending on you get product or not
  }
}
```